# Python / Pandas / SQL table issues

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I was hoping someone could help me, I have a task to do for my College course using Python and SQlite.

I have two excel sheets I would like to make into two tables and a left join on some finance information. I have started by importing the two sheets into pandas and what I thought was creating two tables, but if I'm honest I don't know where I am going wrong. The spreadsheets contain a lot more Columns than I would like to use in the SQL database. Could this be a problem?

I am eventually presented with error code "OperationalError: table Lockedlist has no column named Site Ref"

```
import pandas as pd

Lockedlist_panda = pd.read_excel (r'Location of Lockedlist_panda')
PO1report_panda = pd.read_excel (r'Location of PO1report_panda')

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("data_superstore1.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql='''CREATE TABLE Lockedlist (
    NR TEXT,
    Programme TEXT NOT NULL,
    Sub_Region TEXT NOT NULL,
    Site_Type TEXT NOT NULL,
    MS13_Actual TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(NR)
    )'''

cursor.execute(sql)
print("Table created successfully........")

#Commit your changes in the database
conn.commit()

#Closing the connection
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("data_superstore1.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql='''CREATE TABLE PoReportTable (
    Tracking_Field TEXT,
    VENDOR TEXT NOT NULL,
    Short_Text TEXT NOT NULL,
    COST INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Tracking_Field)
    )'''

cursor.execute(sql)
print("Table created successfully........")

#Commit your changes in the database
conn.commit()

#Closing the connection
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("data_superstore1.db")
Lockedlist_panda.to_sql('Lockedlist', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
PO1report_panda.to_sql('PoReportTable', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

#Commit your changes in the database
conn.commit()

#Closing the connection
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed pandas try to insert all columns from the dataframe into the database, hence if it has more columns that what you defined in the database it will complain for the missing columns,

Try to limit your dataframe to the columns you want first:

```py
Lockedlist_panda = Lockedlist_panda[["NR","Programme","Sub_Region","Site_Type","MS13_Actual" ]]
```

Comment: Out of Interest, could I create the two table names and then go straight to the panda.to_sql function?

Comment: I'm not sure i undestand this question, if you want to use an existing table with the append option, the columns from your data frame have to match the column from the table, so you need to have a middle operation, an other way could be to use the replace option and let pandas overwrite your table with all columns from the dataframe. Also it is not mandatory, to commit, close and reopen a new database connection between each operation.

Comment: Thank you, ideally I would like the SQL tables to match all the columns from the dataframe. How would I use the replace option?

Comment: in the to_sql call replace "append" with "replace", if the table already exists it will drop it and recreate it with all columns before inserting.
`Lockedlist_panda.to_sql('Lockedlist', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)`


documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Thank you! I think that's worked now, I can't give you feedback as I have too little reputation but thanks!